# Is it possible to perform a descent like the picture below which I share?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, aeronautical-charts, approach, holding, instrument-approaches

[image]In the picture, after crossing the VOR fix aircraft does not complete a parallel holding and directly descent on the other side of the racetrack outbound track. In my opinion with Jeppesen General Airway Manual, after crossing the CRL VOR, pilot should fly 1-minute on the inbound course with outbound heading and then turn right to intercept inbound course to VOR. After the completion of this holding, pilot can turn left to fly racetrack on outbound heading, right? It's clear that the descent in the picture makes the job easier, but I don't think this is possible procedurally. Because, according to the point I underlined in the Jeppesen Airway Manual, it is necessary to intercept inbound course first to make a parallel entry to the racetrack descent ? I would be grateful if you could clarify this issue.[image]

Comment: Can you confirm that the green line appears in the illustration in the Jeppesen manual you quoted?

Comment: Sorry but it is not. The approach on the picture above is from my flight school's training manual. So, I thought that maybe the instructor draw that approach line (green) for making it easier to approach, although it is not procedural.

Comment: You are saying it isn't procedural, but I'm still not sure why you believe that is the case.  Given what I added to my answer below, why do you think that the green line is not correct?

Comment: I guess I can't convey my problem correctly because my English is not good or I can't understand what you are saying, please excuse me. The reason is that why I think that the green line is not correct : The approach chart wants us a to apply a "racetrack" not a reversal approach like "procedure turn" or "baseturn". But in the picture, green aproach is kinda like a 80-260 degree turn and it is a reversal approach. Also I can mention that the green appproach line is approximately on the opposite direction of final approach course. In my opinion, first I should apply parallel entry to...

Comment: ... holding and than I should commence my descent with exactly same line on the chart which is a outbound descent part of racetrack approach (blue line). If the other  approach (green line) is completely normal, I guess I should accept it can be apply too without any concern like obstacles or traffic issues. At the end of this conversation, I have to make myself accept that this approach is normal.

Comment: By the way, thank you for your time, sir. I am grateful.

Comment: You are welcome.  If the goal is to become established on the outbound leg of the long racetrack as efficiently as possible, a tear drop entry would work best.  But from that North sector, the standard rules of holding entry apply.  Your blue line just doesn't match anything that is taught, and is inefficient.  There is no compelling reason to not follow the green line, either in writing or common sense.  I believe you are overthinking this.

Comment: If your interpretation was correct, I would expect clear language like: "crossing the fix from the North, enter holding pattern via parallel entry.  Once established in holding, begin descent on the outbound leg to 10 DME."

Comment: Oh my god, this is exactly what I want to point out. Sorry for my confusing English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have completed the outbound leg, turned right and intercepted the inbound course, your parallel entry is complete.  If you cross the fix for the second time you would turn left and hold as published.  You are established at that point.

The only thing paragraph "b" is saying is that you need to intercept the inbound course, just as you have drawn it.  They don't want you to just make a right turn and proceed direct, you need to get over and track the inbound course.

**ADDENDUM**  *(Thanks for the clarification...)*
Remember, the point of this procedure is not to enter the racetrack holding pattern as expeditiously as possible, it is to reverse course and allow you enough straightaway to intercept and fly the localizer/ILS approach.

If you had been issued holding instructions it would not be a problem to shorten your outbound leg and fly the blue line, (especially presuming the inside racetrack is the holding pattern) but you wouldn't want to do that if you plan to fly the approach.

In fact, paragraph "b" is explicitly telling you NOT to do this!  "Shall not return directly to the facility without first intercepting the inbound track" means you need to extend your outbound leg far enough so that when you reverse course you can intercept and fly the inbound course.  Your blue line does not do that, it actually "returns directly to the facility" WITHOUT intercepting the inbound track.  (well, you might have drawn a *tiny* little bit of straightaway showing an intercept, but hopefully you get my point...)

Does that help?

Comment: I was just asking if this approach is possible procedurally. Because although the plane entered parallel to the hold, it started to descend directly on the opposite side of the racetrack leg without intercepting inbound. By the meaning of the intercepting here, I do not mean to establish the final approach course. What I mean by the meaning of intercepting was to fly outbound heading on the inbound course and than flying directly to VOR for applying the complete procedure of parallel entrance for holding.

Comment: You are not expected to intercept the inbound course and track it outbound.  You go parallel to it.  So again, maybe I'm not totally clear what your confusion is, or what you mean by "possible procedurally"...

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank you for your comments and help. For easier understanding, I have shown my idea by drawing it on the chart with a blue line. In my opinion, wouldn't the holding and racetrack have to be flown on the blue colored route because of the procedure? That's all I want to ask.